# Splunk: regex - No events counted

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to extract a field after a specific expression using regex and then running a query which counts the events where this condition is met. I did this:

```
query | rex field=_raw "text: (?<value>\d+)" | timechart partial=f span=5m count as numbers | where value > 3
```

There are some log-entries for which value is greater than 3, but nevertheless this events are not counted. What did I do wrong here and why did I not get a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your where before your time chart

[image]

Using the 8 events, I can select those which are greater than 3

```
source="splunk.txt" host="stack" index="stack" sourcetype="raw_line_break"
| rex "text: (?<value>\d)"
| where value > 3
| timechart partial=f span=5m count as numbers
```

this returns me a count of 2 since only two events in that time window were greater than 3

[image]